# asp.net unity dependency injection doesn't work well

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, unity-container

I am using the mvc 3 framework of asp.net, I have created a UnityControllerFactory that implements the IControllerFactory interface:

```
...
public class UnityControllerFactory : IControllerFactory
{
    private IUnityContainer _container;
    private IControllerFactory _innerFactory;

    public UnityControllerFactory(IUnityContainer container)
        : this(container, new DefaultControllerFactory())
    {
    }

    protected UnityControllerFactory(IUnityContainer container,
                                     IControllerFactory innerFactory)
    {
        _container = container;
        _innerFactory = innerFactory;
    }
public IController CreateController(RequestContext requestContext,
                                        string controllerName)
    {
        try
        {
            IController controller = _container.Resolve<IController>(controllerName.ToLowerInvariant);

            return controller;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            var msg = ex.Message;
            return _innerFactory.CreateController(requestContext, controllerName);
        }

    }
...
```

and in the Application_Start(), I have:

```
protected void Application_Start() {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);


        IUnityContainer container = GetUnityContainer();
        container.RegisterType<IRepository<User>, LiveRepository<User>>();
        DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new UnityDependencyResolver(container));
        ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(new UnityControllerFactory(container));
        ...

    }
```

I test this with a home controller

```
public class HomeController : Controller{
    IRepository<User> userRepo;
    public HomeController(IRepository<User> userRepo)
    {
         this.userRepo = userRepo;
    }
    ...
}
```

When I run the app, I can not build the home controller at all.
in the line:

```
IController controller = _container.Resolve<IController>(controllerName.ToLowerInvariant);
```

I get an exception says:

**"Resolution of the dependency failed, type = "System.Web.Mvc.IController", name =
"homecontroller". Exception occurred while: while resolving.

### Exception is: InvalidOperationException - The current type, System.Web.Mvc.IController, is an interface and cannot be constructed. Are you missing a type mapping?

At the time of the exception, the container was: Resolving System.Web.Mvc.IController,homecontroller"**

but even with the default controller factory using the line:

```
_innerFactory.CreateController(requestContext, controllerName);
```

I still cannot build the controller at all, please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend you taking a look at the [following blog post](http://blog.janjonas.net/2011-03-12/asp_net-mvc_3-dependency-injection-unity_2) which illustrates how to use a custom DependencyResolver with Unity in an ASP.NET MVC 3 application.

Comment: well, thanks, but I really want to know why the failure, is it just because of a [Dependency] attribute?

Comment: @baboonWorksFine, no it's because of a conflict between your custom controller factory and `UnityDependencyResolver`. Those two are mutually exclusive. So you should either write your custom controller factory as you did, or rely on the one provided by unity. I would recommend you use a dependency resolver in ASP.NET MVC 3 as it allows you to inject dependencies in many places into the framework.